# automatically refresh Sheets chart in Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have a chart within google sheets that I would like to have automatically update in google slides every hour. I know you can refresh using the Tools menu and selecting linked objects but I would really like to automate this process without use of a Slides AddOn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to refresh a chart in Google Slides every 1 hour.
- The chart was put from Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, all charts in all slides in the Google Slides are refreshed.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var slidesId = "###";  // Please set the Slides ID.

  SlidesApp.openById(slidesId).getSlides()
  .forEach(function(s) {
    s.getSheetsCharts().forEach(function(c) {
      c.refresh();
    });
  });
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, all charts in 1st slide in the Google Slides are refreshed.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var slidesId = "###";  // Please set the Slides ID.

  SlidesApp.openById(slidesId).getSlides()[0]
  .getSheetsCharts()
  .forEach(function(c) {
    c.refresh();
  });
}
```

### Note:

- In order to automatically run every 1 hour, [please install the time-driven trigger to the function of `myFunction()`.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) By this, `myFunction()` is run every 1 hour.

### References:

- [getSheetsCharts()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/layout#getSheetsCharts())
- [refresh()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/sheets-chart#refresh())
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.